# combining data frames from two lists

Tags: r

I have two lists of data frames. In each list a data frame has a column with the same name and values. As an example:

```
x <- list(data.frame(i=as.character(1:5),x=rnorm(5),z=rnorm(5)),
          data.frame(i=as.character(1:5),x=rnorm(5),z=rnorm(5)))

y <- list(data.frame(i=as.character(5:1),x1=rnorm(5),z1=rnorm(5)),
          data.frame(i=as.character(5:1),x1=rnorm(5),z1=rnorm(5)))
```

I would like to combine the two lists into one so that each element of the new list is a data frame with the following columns: `i, x, z, x1, z1`). That is I would like a list of two data frames each with five rows and the five columns I mentioned. I could not find a solution to this (for example, found how to concatenate dfs in a list in one df). I thought to use `lapply` and pass the function merge(`x,y, by= i)`, but I do not know what the first argument (I.e. data used) should be.
Please note that the values in the common column are not in the same order (in the example they are reversed but in my data they are mixed). So let me know if your solution would require ordering the column first. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is what you want:

```
map2(x, y, ~ inner_join(.x, .y))
```

```
[[1]]
  i          x          z         x1         z1
1 1  0.7715183 -0.6933826 -0.3335239  0.5957587
2 2 -0.3824746 -0.7248827 -1.6736241 -1.2248904
3 3  0.3412777 -0.3711940  0.9334678  0.4043867
4 4 -0.4225862 -1.6653314  1.0369985  1.1808140
5 5  0.7468157  0.1704126 -0.1470796 -1.6237296

[[2]]
  i           x          z         x1          z1
1 1  0.69264103 -0.6640663 -0.2253319  0.26323254
2 2 -0.07861775  0.7914119  0.3725911  0.02854667
3 3 -0.86588724 -0.5519633 -1.5114177 -0.14283509
4 4  1.16069947  1.1299540 -0.4207173 -1.15829758
5 5  2.13867104 -0.9668079  0.1082068 -2.74714297
```

Comment: sorry, kitu. I probably was not clear about the desired output. My desired output would be a list with two data frames. Each df would have 5 rows and 5 columns.

Comment: I changed my answer to that :)

Comment: kitu, it works on my example well. But on my data it does not. here is the code and the error final <- map2(results1, results2, ~ inner_join(.results1, .results2))
Error in inner_join(.results1, .results2) : object '.results1' not found
> Should I have .x and .y in inner_joint?

Comment: Yes, try `map2(results1, results2, ~ inner_join(.x, .y))`

Comment: Very nice dear ktiu :)

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(tidyverse)
map2(x, y, ~left_join(.x, .y, by = 'i'))
#> [[1]]
#>   i          x         z         x1         z1
#> 1 1 -0.8773188  1.204293  1.2809946  0.9016632
#> 2 2 -0.4091583 -1.128325  0.7973242 -0.1010260
#> 3 3  1.3747095  0.784787 -1.6927698 -1.1568878
#> 4 4  0.7565917 -1.104594  1.0663122 -0.1439810
#> 5 5  0.9662782 -1.039493 -0.2620102 -0.4941850
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   i         x          z         x1          z1
#> 1 1 0.7871544 -1.0974764  1.2926863  0.99399623
#> 2 2 1.3705341 -0.1047783  1.3612606 -0.01155390
#> 3 3 0.9984027 -0.2466980  0.4554107 -1.38307942
#> 4 4 0.7096952  0.7500738 -0.4586198  0.02311739
#> 5 5 0.1883204 -0.6399546  0.1496794 -0.43233764
```

Its baseR equivalent

```r
Map(function(.x, .y) merge(.x, .y, by = 'i'), x, y)
#> [[1]]
#>   i            x           z         x1         z1
#> 1 1  1.163081705  0.71855088  0.7981572  0.1029179
#> 2 2  0.876645119 -0.08615626  0.7299087  0.9782025
#> 3 3 -1.460452798 -0.14551233 -0.3380226 -1.1168602
#> 4 4 -0.004574267 -0.36117459  0.2183281 -0.9045827
#> 5 5 -0.836010524  0.12336598 -0.9046551 -0.2670896
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   i          x          z          x1         z1
#> 1 1 -1.1605742  0.3233873 -0.16685367 -1.0579590
#> 2 2  1.5723944  0.5120253 -0.66373500  0.3241323
#> 3 3 -1.5562135  1.1251436  0.06805823 -2.2889400
#> 4 4  0.2782484  0.4134606 -0.11763939 -0.9060669
#> 5 5 -0.4821373 -0.7170258  0.72466946 -1.4457480
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
Map(function(u, v) setDT(u)[v, on = .(i)], x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usig `{dplyr}` and `{purrr}`

```
purrr::map2(x, y, dplyr:::left_join, by = 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also use the following solution:

```
library(purrr)

map2(x, y, ~ .x %>%  bind_cols(.y %>% select(-i)))

[[1]]
  i           x          z         x1         z1
1 1  0.17590858 -2.5917377 -0.5603591  0.5810495
2 2  0.03199955 -0.1387498 -0.5948580 -1.5914561
3 3 -1.51798345 -0.1991066  0.5550439  0.9111812
4 4  0.03178260  2.4638499 -1.1169747  0.6084738
5 5  2.41686436 -0.7952663  0.4207237  0.5133366

[[2]]
  i           x           z         x1         z1
1 1 -0.07731912 -0.08303112  1.2116506 -1.0381454
2 2 -0.88351320 -1.50888504  0.8762129  1.5319386
3 3 -0.04033662  0.48264589 -0.3644170 -1.3051433
4 4  0.81795108  0.22947344  0.7192894 -1.2796247
5 5  1.19298096  2.29746662  0.9020253  0.8600827
```